# Xcode bot server is not recognizing multiple working copies

Tags: ios, xcode, git, frameworks, xcode7

I have 2 Xcode projects:

1. Reusable code across different apps, built using a framework
2. My app

The app's project is within a workspace, and in that workspace I also have my framework pulled in, and it builds and runs fine locally.

Xcode's source control menu shows both working copies, as expected.

The issue is that when I add a new Xcode bot to reflect this workspace setup for my app, the bot setup system only recognizes the working copy for my app, so when it runs an integration, it fails almost immediately because it has not checked out the code for the framework.

I have configured the framework as "required during checkout", though this does not seem to be reflected in any of Xcode's config files because that change does not show up in source control, and when I restart Xcode, this gets reset to "optional".

How can I get Xcode bots to recognize the working copy for my framework so it can check it out as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem was caused by the fact that Xcode 7.2 does not generate the necessary xccheckout file for the bot server to pick up on the multiple working copies. To fix it, I opened my project in Xcode 6.4, let it automatically create the xccheckout file, committed and pushed to my repo, and then edited my bot (still in Xcode 6.4). After doing that and editing the bot, it is working fine now.

I thought I'd post this in case anyone else runs into the same issue.